# sql server 2008 database diagrams table name search

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, diagram

I have SQL server 2008 enterprise with a database containing up to 100 tables. I generated a database diagram with all of the tables because I want to get an overview of the database.

My question is : How can I quickly find the  diagram I want, are there any search functions regarding to diagram search ?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server the diagrams are stored in the sysdiagrams table, which is created whenever a diagram is created. The table definition is as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sysdiagrams](
    [name] [sysname] NOT NULL,
    [principal_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [diagram_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [version] [int] NULL,
    [definition] [varbinary](max) NULL)
```

Along with the table, a few stored procedures are also created.

- sp_alterdiagram
- sp_dropdiagram
- sp_creatediagram
- sp_renamediagram
- sp_helpdiagramdefinition
- sp_helpdiagrams
- sp_upgradediagrams

The `sp_helpdiagrams` procedure will give you a listing of all the diagrams you currently have.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I pretty much like to locate the graph in the diagram, because one page has so many graphs

Answer (score 0):

Actually SQL Server 2008 doesn't support any feature similar to what you are asking. You have to do the searching manually.